# Angular indexOf not outputting text

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to output the name "Sam" on the screen in a ng-show using indexOf, but nothing ever appears. Any help is appreciated.

html

```
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <div ng-controller="ArrayController">
         <div ng-repeat="product in products">
            <div ng-show="product.name.indexOf('Sam') == 2">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>


      <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="app.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

angular

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ArrayController', ['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.products = [
{
name: 'Joe'

},
{
name: 'Bill'
},
{
name: 'Sam'
}
];

}]);
```

Comment: Also keep in mind that your test will be **never** equals to 2.

Comment: Sorry but I'd also suggest you learn about what Array.indexOf does https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: @SamiTriki, Even String has `indexOf()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: Do you need this `https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/hwne9jmu/`

Comment: Thank you Satpal for showing me a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution using `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="ArrayController">
        <div ng-repeat="product in products">
          <div ng-if="product.name.indexOf('Sam') > -1">{{product.name}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ArrayController', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.products = [
    {
        name: 'Joe'
    },
    {
        name: 'Bill'
    },
    {
        name: 'Sam'
    }
  ];
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-show="product.name.indexOf('Sam') == 2"></div>
```

This will show the div if `product.name` contains the string "Sam" starting at its third character (i.e. "xxSam").  That probably isn't what you want.

The div is empty, so will not be visible to the user even if the `ng-show` is truthy.  That, too, is probably not what you want.

I'm pretty sure what you *do* want is this:

```
<div>{{product.name}}</div>
```